# Логические операции С++

Tags: c++, логические-выражения

Недавно начал изучать С++. Выполняю упражнение на перевод температур по шкалам.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
        int a;
        float c, f, t;
        char ch;
        do {
        cout << "Нажмите 1 для перевода шкалы Цельсия в шкалу Фаренгейта" << endl;
        cout << "        2 для перевода шкалы Фаренгейта в шкалу Цельсия: ";
        cin >> a;
        if ( a != 1 || a != 2 )
        {
            cout << "Неверное значение!" << endl;
            cout << "Попробуй еще раз." << endl;
            continue;
        }
        switch(a)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "Введите t по Цельсия: ";
                cin >> c;
                t = (c * 9.5) + 32;
                cout << "Температура " << c << " по Цельсию равна " << t << " градусам по Фаренгейту." << endl;
                break; 
            case 2:
                cout << "Введите t по Фаренгейту: ";
                cin >> f;
                t = (f - 32) * 5.9;
                cout << "Температура " << f << " по Фаренгейту равна " << t << " градусам по Цельсия." << endl; 
                break;
    }
    cout << "Еще раз?(y/n): ";
    cin >> ch;
    } while (ch != 'n');
    return 0;
    }
```

Одно не могу понять. Вот строчка кода:

```
if ( a != 1 || a != 2 )
```

Если а не равно 1 **ИЛИ** а не равно 2, то должен выполняться вот этот кусочек кода:

```
   {
    cout << "Неверное значение!" << endl;
    cout << "Попробуй еще раз." << endl;
    continue;
           }
```

а если я введу 1 или 2, то программа по идее должна пойти дальше, но вместо этого она выполняет все тот же код. Помогите пожалуйста понять как это работает:)

Comment: Если a равно 1, то a не равно 2 и условие успешно выполняется. Если a равно 2, то a не равно 1 и условие тоже успешно выполняется. Дальше программа и не может пойти, потому что условие выполняется в любом случае

Comment: Иначе говоря, слово **ИЛИ** означает, что подходит *любое* из перечисленных условий. Вам нужно использовать **И**.

Comment: До меня дошло. Спасибо за ответ. Это решило проблему.

Comment: Лучше вместо этого  в теле  switch выполнить инструкцию при других значениях  Вот так:     default:
   cout << "Неверное значение!\nПопробуй еще раз.\n" ;